# $u_t + \sin(tu_x) = x^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For the PDE: $u_t + sin(tu_x) = x^2$ with initial condition $u(0,x) = \sin x$, how should I solve this.

I thought of trying to take the Fourier transform to reduce to an ODE but I'm not seeing how to do $\mathcal{F}(\sin(tu_x))$. Any ideas?

Comment: You could potentially solve using characteristics but in general, you can't expect to solve most nonlinear PDE.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$u_t+\sin tu_x=x^2$ with $u(0,x)=\sin x$

$u_{xt}+tu_{xx}\cos tu_x=2x$ with $u(0,x)=\sin x$

Let $v=u_x$ ,

Then $v_t+tv_x\cos tv=2x$ with $v(0,x)=\cos x$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$ , letting $t(0)=0$ , we have $t=s$

$\therefore\begin{cases}\dfrac{dx}{ds}=s\cos sv\\\dfrac{dv}{ds}=2x\end{cases}$

Hence $\dfrac{d^2v}{ds^2}=2s\cos sv$